# Chrome Web-SQL Data Manipulation Causes Crash

Tags: google-chrome, crash, google-chrome-devtools, web-sql

I'm usgin Google Chrome Version 51.0.2704.84 m.
I have a web app witch use Web-SQL for storage. Since today every thing was working fine. But now EVERY data manipulation causes chrome to crash. I used the "Developer Tools" window and under resources > Web SQL, I entered a simple Update code for a table. It also caused chrome to crash and show a dialogue "DevTools was disconnected from the page ...". This is my tsql:

```
update app_settings set ServerIPAddress = '111'
```

But I was surprised after I reloaded the page and checked the value of that column in my table, witch was successfully updated.

Please share your experiences with me.

Comment: Try the following:

1. Open up http://example.com (or any simple site)
2. In Console, run: `var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (id unique, text)');
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO foo (id, text) VALUES (1, "synergies")');
});`
3. In Resources, under Web SQL > mydb, enter `update foo set text = '111'`

Does it crash still? If so, it could be an extension that is to blame and you could disable them and re-test.

Comment: No. It doesn't crash for other sites.

Comment: But strangely It's still crashing when I run your code at my web app. I have no extension and to be sure, I have reset chrome and it's still not working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved simply by running my application through **IIS** instead of **file:///**. Although I still don't know the actual technical cause of this malfunction. I hope it helps somebody.